# slurm example for a simple executable file

Tags: c, slurm

I am a a freshman to programming in SLURM. Is there any possibility to execute MATLAB code using sbatch.

(I tried using MATLAB as a executable for getting some error /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/matlab: 1: /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/util/oscheck.sh: /lib64/libc.so.6: not found)

The MATLAB code plots contours for the files dumped by a C code into the working directory.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<library>
FILE *first_file;
main()
{
MatrixXd A = Eigen::MatrixXd::Random(10, 10);
    first_file = fopen("first_file.dat","w");
for (int i=0;i<10;i++) 
    fprintf(first_file," %lf \t",A.data(i));
}
```

I compiled the code using gcc file.c -o file
and later called by matlab using system('file') command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Tutorial](http://www.ceci-hpc.be/slurm_tutorial.html) on how to create and launch a job. 
[Tutorial](http://www.nersc.gov/users/computational-systems/cori/running-jobs/example-batch-scripts/) This one provides a lot of examples for sbatch and SLURM

All you need is to take the executable and place it in the sbatch script like you would in the command line.

Comment: @maharshi kintada, Please make sure you research the particular issue before posting on this site. This will allow you to learn more and not be flagged by any moderators on stackoverflow, Thank you.

Comment: Thank you abeltre1 for your suggestion and your help.

Comment: It is my pleasure to help @maharshikintada